# React-bootstrap-table rowevent not updating state immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have researched on immediate state update using hooks and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). However, I am finding a challenge implementing it in my case.

```
const rowEvents = {
  onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
    setMessageid(row.pm_id);      
    console.log(row.pm_id);
    console.log(messageid);
    if (row.custompassword === true) {
      handleShow1();
    } else {
      decipher();
      handleShow2();
    }
  },
};
```

How do I get the current set state of messageid by adding it to useEffect so that it detects any changes? decipher() uses messageid therefore it needs to be current one.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your logic correctly you can have the `decipher()` function, inside a useEffect and just set the state like usual. Just remember to set the message id as a dependency.

```js
const [messageId, setMessageId] = useState("");

useEffect(() =>{
  decipher()
  //useEffect will be called after the messsageId state changes
}, [messageId])

const rowEvents = {
   onClick: (e, row, rowindex) =>{
   // do other stuff
   setMessageId(row.pm_id)
   }
}
```